# mysql type varchar versus text and blob

Tags: mysql

I have a form that has a text area in it. The user types a comment and it gets inserted into my database. My problem arises when the comment has an apostrophe in it...When I go to retrieve the comment and display it on the screen the apostrophe doesn't show up, and seems to be transformed into some weird character. Do I need to choose a certain mysql data type (varchar, text, blob) to avoid this?

Comment: This isn't about the data type or encoding, it is related to how the apostrophe is escaped on input or output.  It must be escaped when output as part of an attribute in HTML.  Post your code, both the bit that saves the field into the database, and the bit that displays it back to the screen.

Comment: This is PHP, I'm guessing (though it isn't tagged)?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix your problem is that you can encode your data before your store them into database, after encoding, there will be no special character, and when you retrieve it, you can decode, such as urlencode ,urldecode.

Hope helps!

Comment: No no no, don't encode text data in the database. You need to _escape_ it for safe insertion, but should store it in its exact original form. Encode it appropriately for the output medium at output time.

Comment: so insert it into the database as is and then encode as I'm retrieving it?

Comment: It depends, if there are some db-unfriendly characters such as quote, you need to replace this character or encode it when inserting. if there are some html-unfriendly characters such as "<" and ">", you need to replace them when displaying, while with urlencode and urldecode, you can solve all these problems at one time, the disadvantage is that urlencode will make the size of      the data more larger

Comment: @matttuman Escape it for insertion (against SQL injection) - proper escaping will cause it to be stored in its original form - then encode it correctly for output.